# How to make Minio-client (from host) talk with Minio-server(docker container)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04, minio

I am running a minio-server in the container of docker-compose. I am trying to upload a file to the minio-server in the container, from the host machine (Ubuntu) (instead of container) by using minio-client (python SDK). 
I did not make it happen as expected. 
I am not clear if it is because of my endpoint(URL), or due to the connection issue between container and host?

The endpoints i tried:

url_1 = 'http://minio:9000' # from my default setup for minio link;

url_2 = 'http://localhost:9000/minio/test' # from Minio browser.

For url_1, what i got is: " botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: http://minio:9000/test ". 
The line of error: s3.create_bucket(Bucket='test')

For url_2, what i got is: " All access to this bucket has been disabled. ". 
The line of error: s3.create_bucket(Bucket='test')

I tried the similar thing: activating my minio-server and minio-client both in my host machine. Then i upload file from the minio-client to the minio-server. I can see those uploaded files in Minio browser in localhost.

#########   python script uploading files

```
import boto3

from botocore.client import Config

import os

import getpass

my_url1='http://minio:9000' # this is from os.environ['S3_URL']
my_url2='http://localhost:9000/minio/test' # this is from browser

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                endpoint_url=my_url2,
                aws_access_key_id=os.environ['USER'],
                aws_secret_access_key = getpass.getpass('Password:'),
                config = Config(signature_version='s3v4'),
                region_name='us-east-1')

print ('********', s3)

s3.create_bucket(Bucket='test')

uploadfile= os.getcwd()+'/'+'test.txt'
s3.Bucket('testBucket').upload_file(uploadfile,'txt')
```

#########   docker-yml file for Minio

```
minio:
   image: minio/minio
   entrypoint:
      - minio
      - server
      -/data
   ports:
      - "9000:9000"
   environment:
      minio_access_key = username
      minio_secret_key = password

mc:
   image: minio/mc
   environment: 
      minio_access_key = username
      minio_secret_key = password
   entrypoint:
      /bin/sh -c     
   depends_on:
      minio
```

i expected to see the uploaded files from the minio browser('http://localhost:9000/minio/test') , just like what i did from activating minio-server and minio-client both at the host.

Answer (score 3):

With default docker networking, you would have to try to access minio at http://localhost:9000 on your host. So you can just use this URL in your Python script. The http://minio:9000 will work from containers on the same docker network as your minio server.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Pyminio](https://github.com/mmm1513/pyminio) client instead of boto3.

```py
import os
from pyminio import Pyminio

pyminio_client = Pyminio.from_credentials(
    endpoint='http://localhost:9000/',
    access_key=os.environ['USER'],
    secret_key=getpass.getpass('Password:')
)

pyminio_client.mkdirs('/test/')

pyminio_client.put_file(
    to_path='/test/',
    file_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test.txt')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this configuration in your compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
    
    minio:
        image: "minio/minio"
        container_name: mi
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        environment:
            - "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=ACCRESS"
            - "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=SECRET"
        restart: always
        command: server /data
    mc:
        image: minio/mc
        container_name: mc
        network_mode: host
        entrypoint: >
          /bin/sh -c "
          /usr/bin/mc config host add minio http://127.0.0.1:9000 ACCESS SECRET;
          /usr/bin/mc rm -r --force minio/psb-new;
          /usr/bin/mc mb minio/psb-new;
          /usr/bin/mc policy set public minio/psb-new;
          exit 0;
          "
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```